# google access api with php curl

Tags: php, curl, google-api, libcurl

I am trying to fetch my user's emails with google api & curl, and I am stuck on redeeming access token. I get the key no problem, but when it comes to token, google just returns json

```
{"error" : "invalid_request"}
```

below is a snippet which redeems code for token (well at least it supposed to)

```
$code = urlencode($_GET["code"]);
$secret = "MYSECRET";
$client_id = "MYCLIENTID";
$redirect_uri = urlencode("http://www.mysupersite.com/callback.html");
$grant_type = "authorization_code";

$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

$headers = array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

$post = "code=".$code."&client_id=".$client_id."&secret=".$secret."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&grant_type=".$grant_type;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($json);
```

I'm really stuck and google api never tells you what exactly is wrong.

**UPD** I know there's a lib for this kind of calls, but I'm solving one simple task (well according to google api documentation) and simply see no point in including loads of other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay my bad - $_GET["secret"] needs to be $_GET["client_secret"]